# Have iTunes on Mac show the iPad with wi-fi

Tags: itunes, ipad, wifi, airport, bug

Usually, when I launch iTunes on my Mac and I have my iPad on nearby, iTunes shows the iPad at the top right. Then I can do a backup of my iPad in wi-fi.

*Sometimes, randomly, iTunes fails to show the iPad, and I have to plug the iPad to the Mac so that it appear in iTunes.*

I have encountered this problem with my 2 iPads.

1. **How can I have iTunes show the iPad ?**
2. **Besides, it would help to know what conditions trigger the failure.**

Comment: If its not too disruptive, try this: shut your wireless router off; on the iPads and other iDevices, remove any saved wifi networks, then power them down. Lastly, power down any other wifi-enabled devices. Boot the wifi router, give it a minute to gets it legs, then reconnect to your local wifi net on each iDevice. Boot any other wifi-enabled devices last. There has been [considerable discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6542301?start=0&tstart=0) on the Apple Support Communities about this and similar problems. It is most reliable when the device is plugged into a power source.

Comment: @IconDaemon — The discussion you link is about iOS 8. My iPads have iOS 7 and 5.

Comment: Put that information in your question, then, with the exact models of the iPads and their respective installed iOS versions. It'll will help others to assist you. Although not specific to your predicament, the steps delineated in my comment are generic and will help to make sure your wireless network, with all its connected devices, is re-created afresh to eliminate any oddities. It has fixed wifi issues for me in the past, both personally and professionally.

Comment: @IconDaemon - Now, the problem also occurs with iPads in iOS 8.